# ARKit 4.0 – Ignoring the ".ceiling" from horizontal plane detection

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am trying to have my code detect horizontal planes in order to find the floor. My floor is the biggest horizontal surface below the device at starting point. My current algorithm is working to find the biggest horizontal plane and identifies it as floor, but it also counts the ceiling as a horizontal plane - which it shouldn't. I have been looking around for a way around this, but no dice.

Any help is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
var areas = [Float]()

for grid1 in grids {
    let a = grid1.planeGeometry.width * grid1.planeGeometry.height
    areas.append(Float(a))
}

for grid2 in grids {
    let area = grid2.planeGeometry.width * grid2.planeGeometry.height

     if (Float(area)==areas.max()) {
         grid2.floored(state: true)
     } else {
         grid2.floored(state: false)
     }
}
```

**EDIT**

> To clarify the definition of the floor, it is the biggest, lowest plane detected from the device's initial starting point. So, for example, if two planes (say a carpet and the floor itself) are detected separately and are of the same size, the lower one would be the floor. But, if the carpet covers more space then it is the floor.

Answer (score 1):

In ***ARKit 4.0*** it's still a [gettable-only property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arplaneanchor/3020726-classification) – it says you how ARKit classifies a surface:

```
public var classification: ARPlaneAnchor.Classification { get }
```

Use a ***RealityKit***'s property instead that is **settable** and conforms to OptionSet protocol:

```
let surfaceClassification: AnchoringComponent.Target.Classification = [.floor, 
                                                                       .seat]
```

In a real code it may look like this:

```
import RealityKit

let arView = ARView(frame: cgRect)

let box = MeshResource.generateBox(size: 0.25)
let entity = ModelEntity(mesh: box)

let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal,
                 classification: .floor,
                  minimumBounds: [2.0, 2.0])

anchor.addChild(entity)
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

Comment: I have tried adding a guard to check if the plane's anchor is floor, but it is not equatable. I tried something like ```guard planeAnchor.classification == .floor else {return}```

Comment: I like the Realitykit solution, but in the whole project I've been using ARPlaneAnchor as the type of my anchors and it has been doing fine so far. Is there no way to keep using ARkit other than switching all my anchors?

Comment: There's no solution except `let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: ARAnchor())`

Comment: Tried modifying my code, but came to find out that casting from ARAnchor to AnchorEntity does not work and your solution for initializing it won't either because it doesn't have init(). So, bottom line of this approach is I'd need to remake the whole thing to use RealityKit instead of ARKit and SceneKit

Comment: Yes. You should use ARKit+RealityKit instead of ARKit+SceneKit (if you need to manage `classification`).

Comment: But ARKit won't work with RealityKit because casting from ARAnchor to AnchorEntity always fails

Comment: But you can use many classes of ARKit that RealityKit doesn't have. So ARKit+RealityKit is a robust choice.